# Taking only one kwarg

Tags: python, keyword-argument

I'm looking to create a get_user() function that retrieves a user record from a database. The only thing is, I'd like to allow some flexibility in how it's being called and allow them to call the function as:

get_user(username="testuser") or get_user(email="testacct@gmail.com") or get_user(uid=7)

My first thought is to define the function as:

```
def get_user(**kwargs):
    c, conn = connection(dict_cursor = True)
    keyword = None # key that's passed in i.e username, email, etc.
    data = c.execute("SELECT * FROM users where %s = %s",[escape_string(keyword), escape_string(kwargs[keyword]),])
    data = c.fetchone()
    conn.close()
    return data
```

My question is, how can I get the one (and assumably the only) keyword without a lengthy series of else if statements?

I could iterate though the kwargs, make a list of the keys, and take only the 0 index of the list, but that seems like a very hacky way to do it. Is there a more pythonic way to expect one keyword argument and take it without going to args and using something like       getuser("email",testacct@gmail.com") ?

Comment: Why have it as a `kwarg` then?  Just have `def get_user(parameter_name, parameter_value):` then something like `if parameter_name not in list_of_parameters:` then throw some exception

Comment: @PatrickHaugh - On further thought, I suppose there's nothing wrong with that.

Answer (score 0):

Try `k, v = next(iter(kwargs.items()))` (in Python 2, `k, v = next(kwargs.iteritems()`).

`k` and `v` are then the key and value of the keyword argument.

You could also just do `k = next(iter(kwargs))` in either Python 2 or Python 3. This gets the key and then the value is just `v = kwargs[k]`.

You can test `len(kwargs)` to make sure there's only one keyword argument.

Comment: It comes back with: TypeError: 'dict_items' object is not an iterator

Comment: Updated. Forgot Python 3 doesn't actually return an iterator for `.items()` so had to hrow an `iter()` around it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe a `namedtuple` would work well in this scenario:

```
from collections import namedtuple
def get_user(**kwargs):
   c, conn = connection(dict_cursor = True)
   keyword = None # key that's passed in i.e username, email, etc.
   data = c.execute("SELECT * FROM users where %s = %s",[escape_string(keyword), escape_string(kwargs[keyword]),])
   user_info = namedtuple("user_info", "username, email")
   final_data = map(user_info.make_, data)
   data = [i.email for i in final_data][0] #if you want to email
   conn.close()
   return data
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're certain (it seems so) that there is only one key-value pair you could use [`popitem`](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.popitem) to get it:

```
keyword, value = kwargs.popitem()
```

Just keep in mind that this will remove the key-value pair from the dictionary. Not that it matters in this case.

Comment: That'll with with a dictionary that's unordered? I thought that method was only for lists.

Comment: It's a method on the dictionary (II assume what you meant is `pop`, which is a method on lists). I added a link to the documentation. It will return a random key-value pair. In case there's only one it's that one.